# Unhide Certain Cells in Excel Automatically

Tags: excel, row, hide, cell

I'm facing a problem that I wish you can help me with, the Issue is that I'm trying to create a Code that as follow:

For example Row 1 I wanna Make it Hidden , when the Row is selected I want it to Unhide Automatcally

Please Need your Help Urgentaly

Comment: Cells by themselves cannot be hidden; only full rows. How were you planning to select a cell that is hidden? The `GoTo` command will do it but that generally isn't left for the casual user as a method. If you have been 'trying to create a Code', please show your work so far.

Comment: I had edited the question

Comment: Do you want it hidden like having a height of 0? Or do you want it to have a blank content?

Comment: yes i want it havong a hight og 0

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 1 Then
        Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Once row#1 has been *Hidden* you can use the **Name Box** to return to it.